# how i get title from following response

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, response

How i can get title or body from the following json response?

```
{
    "message": "All Books",
    "data": {
        "current_page": 1,
        "data": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "title": "The Quran",
                "slug": "the-quran",
                "body": "The Holy Quran",
                "book": "/storage/books/1602685137.pdf",
                "cover": "/storage/covers/1602685137.jpg",
                "os": "both",
                "price_ios": 0,
                "price_android": 0,
                "created_at": "2020-10-14T14:18:57.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2020-10-14T14:18:57.000000Z"
            }
        ],
        "first_page_url": "https://book.test/api/v1/books?page=1",
        "from": 1,
        "last_page": 1,
        "last_page_url": "https://book.test/api/v1/books?page=1",
        "links": [
            {
                "url": null,
                "label": "Previous",
                "active": false
            },
            {
                "url": "https://book.test/api/v1/books?page=1",
                "label": 1,
                "active": true
            },
            {
                "url": null,
                "label": "Next",
                "active": false
            }
        ],
        "next_page_url": null,
        "path": "https://book.test/api/v1/books",
        "per_page": 15,
        "prev_page_url": null,
        "to": 1,
        "total": 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't simply repeat words to get around the code/text ratio limits. Instead, add useful information, like what you have already tried and how it is not working for you.

Comment: [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) may be of use to you.

Comment:  ok . next i will try these things if it say need more text

Comment: i am using axios to get reponse :  like (response.data) give all reponse. but i need title ,body..etc

Comment: To access the title from provided structure, use `data.data[0].title`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your JSON is assigned to a variable called `response` you can access the body with:
`let body = response.data.data[0].body`

And the title with
`let title = response.data.data[0].title`

In case you want to loop over the data array in order to get a value for all entries (e.g. title), try this:
`let titles = response.data.data.forEach(entry => console.log(entry.title));`

Answer (score 1):

Say the json is stored in a variable *res*.

Since the second data object is stored as an array [].

```
title = res['data']['data'][0]['title'];
body = res['data']['data'][0]['body'];
```

If you find a case where the array has more than one object, then you will have to change 0 to the index of the object in the array.
Reference:  [www.json.org](https://www.json.org)

Comment: Thanks Daedalus for spotting that. Corrected

Comment: Thanks @Schiphol . i try  your answer but same getting full answer

Comment: You said you are using axios. Is this the output when you log the response.data to console?
Then title = response.data.data.data[0].title